# Displaying data from another file using jQuery not working and displaying views in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#items').load('<?php echo base_url('home/test'); ?>'); 
//alert();
});

</script>
</head>

<body>


<div id="header" style="height:11%;width:100%;background-color:#1F242A;">

<div id="img" style="float:left;">
<img src="/e-com/images/logo.jpg" style="margin-left:130%;" />
</div>
</div>

<div id="left" style="background-color:grey;height:100%;width:13%;float:left;">
</div>

<div id="right" style="background-color:grey;height:100%;width:13%;float:right;">
</div>


<div id="content" style="height:100%;width:70%;float:left;">
<div id="table" style="float:center;">
<table border="0" width="44" style="margin-left:45%;"> 
<tr>
<td><h1><a href="home">Home</a></h1></td>
<td><h1><a href="home">Home</a></h1></td>
<td><h1><a href="home">Home</a></h1></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="items">here</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>


</script>
```

**Firstly**, the script above which is in home_view, should display a few words from test.php, but it's not working. Test.php has paragraph tags and a few words. I am able to display an alert box so jQuery is working.

**Secondly**, how do I do this using codeigniter? How can I send the data to test.php, but load home_view.php?

```
public function test()  
{
    //$data['items'] = $this->product_model->all_items();
    $this->load->view('test');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `base_url()` to get the file loaded & MVC of course

For example

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#items').load('<?php echo base_url("controller/method"); ?>');
});
```

In your method just call the view

```
$this->load->view('test',$data);
```

For you second question if you didn't call it, then it will be useless and PHP code will not be issued or interpreted

So If you **really really** need to view `home_page` and send data to `test` you can

1. AJAX request to the method that will send data, and I think here you will not get any benefit, I don't know what you are trying to achieve
2. Load the test.php view in the home_page.php view and make the container div hidden for example

**In your controller**

```
public function index() 
{
    $test['title'] = "Stackoverflow" ;
    $data['test'] = $test['title']; 
    $data['items'] = $this->product_model->all_items();
    $this->load->view('home_page', $data);

}
```

**In your view home_page.php**

```
<html>
........

<div style='display:none; '>
    <?php $this->load->view('test',$test); ?> 
</div>
```

I hope this can help : ) 
If you need more help just leave a comment :)

Comment: I just want to display some things using jquery without having to refresh the page. I have updated my code but its still not working, please take a look.

Comment: I've tried the script outside the codeigniter folder in htdocs and it is able to fetch the data from another file and display it, so how do I get this working in codeigniter?

Comment: What is your level experience with CodeIgniter ?

Comment: Because you will create just a controller and method and two or one views and it should be very simple

Answer (score 0):

For your first question:

Try

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#items').load('/views/test.php');  # mark the preceding slash
  });
</script>
```

If that not works, check if there is content on yourdomain.com/views/test.php

Comment: I've done that, and nothing. I checked the content in test.php and the words are there. Is it the jquery?

Comment: I've tried the script outside the codeigniter folder in htdocs and it is able to fetch the data from another file and display it, so how do I get this working in codeigniter?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have any experience with CodeIgniter, so I can't help you. But at least you found out that it's not your jQuery, that's a good start :-)